# runtime.h does not compile, included in iPad app

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

A class in my iPad app uses `#import <objc/runtime.h>` to gain access to runtime functions. However, upon compilation (Apple LLVM compiler 2.1), this file does not compile:

`Parse issue: Illegal interface qualifier`

It seems to be on the line `@class Protocol`, near the beginning of the file:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
@class Protocol;
#else
typedef struct objc_object Protocol;
#endif
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 5):

I found that this was caused because the @end directive was missing at the end of a .h file.

I found it by using Terminal to go to the directory containing my .h files and running the command: "tail -n1 *.h" and looking for any files that didn't end with "@end" as they should (at least in my case).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem bleeding through from a previous #import. Check the header file imported immediately prior to your `#import <objc/runtime.h>` and see if it never terminated itself properly.

Comment: @Jordan Can you post some more code? Where is this #import? Is the importing file a .m file?